# How to handle event fired before listener is attached

Tags: javascript, events, dom-events, yui

Code fires event on success ajax response. Event listener is attached in function after this code for some reasons. Is it possible to catch already fired event and handle it on adding listener or I have to change implementation?

Comment: Is there some code you can show to illustrate the problem? Because so far the answer is most likely "there is no way", but it may depend on the situation.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you cannot "store" events, but you could do something like this

```
var events = [],
    object = { test: 'text' };    


item.trigger('event', object);
events.push({ name: 'event', data: object });

item.listenTo('event', function( data )
{

}

// Make sure this is called after the listener is executed, 
// and only once or you will be making multiple triggers
if ( events.length > 0 )
{
    for ( i = 0; i <= events.length; i++ )
    {
        if ( events[i].name = 'event' )
        {
            item.trigger('event', events[i].data);
            events.splice(i, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

(haven't at all tested this code)

Not recommending doing this tho, you should just refactor your code and make sure the listener is executed before any triggers because if it isn't there is probably something wrong with your code. And this is just bad code, you could probably just as easily refactor, but it's up to you.